# Compare dimension of two matrices in R

Tags: r, matrix, dimensions

Having two matrices, `x` and `y`, how may I check if their dimensions match?

I though about comparisons like

```
if(nrow(x) == nrow(y) && ncol(x) == ncol(y)) { ... }
```

or

```
if(min(dim(x) == dim(y)) == 1) { ... }
```

but this doesn't seem quite straigth forward.

**Question:** Is there a single function / single command for matrices to check if they have the same dimension (something like `sameDim(x,y)`)?

Comment: `identical(dim(x), dim(y))`

Comment: @eipi10: Thanks, that looks much more readable compared to my `min` solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by @eipi10, I now use `identical(dim(x), dim(y))`.